# chromium dll dependency on Windows

Tags: chromium

I am building chromium following steps on https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md, it finishes successfully and generated `chrome.exe` runs well. However i found that my `chrome.exe` requires `base.dll` and lots of other dlls but official Chromium builds from https://download-chromium.appspot.com/ doesn't require these dlls.

My question is how can i build my `chrome.exe` to make it work in same way as official package, which means no dependency of these dlls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running a debug version of Chromium which will create many shared libraries to load at runtime. You should build a release  version of Chromium. Set these arguments for release version or the contents of `args.gn`  file in your build folder:

```
is_debug = false
is_component_build = false
```

The first argument will tell `GN` to build release version and the second one will create fewer shared libraries for efficient runtime.